# Http Not Supported Error with Jersey client when using already created config while creating client. Https is working fine

Tags: java, jersey-client

I am using Jersey client to make REST API call to server. Below is the code for the same:

Library: org.glassfish.jersey.client

```
final JerseyStrictSslConfigurationFactory singletonFactory = 
    JerseyStrictSslConfigurationFactory.getDefaultFactory();

final ClientConfig clientConfig = 
            singletonFactory.from(SSLMode.RETAIL_INTERNAL, SslConfigurator.getDefaultContext());
    
Client client =  ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .withConfig(clientConfig) // passing clientConfig direclty here
        .register(JacksonFeature.class)
        .build();

WebTarget somTarget = client.target("https://postman-echo.com").path("/get");

Response resp = somTarget.queryParam("foo", 1).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

System.out.println(resp.getStatus());
```

Now this above code works with res: 200, but if change the target from **https://** to **http://**

```
WebTarget somTarget = client.target("http://postman-echo.com").path("/get");
```

I start getting below error:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.UnsupportedSchemeException: http protocol is not supported
```

*Will add full stack trace if required*

Now if i change the above code a little bit and use new clientconfig object while creating client

```
Client client =  ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .withConfig(new ClientConfig(clientConfig)) // created new client config object instead of using clientConfig directly
        .register(JacksonFeature.class)
        .build();
```

It works with **http://** also and gives 200 status code for both https and http.

Question: Why is this happening that when we use **new ClientConfig** object http is working and if we pass already created **clientConfig** object http not supported error is coming.

Comment: Look at the javadoc. The constructor accepts `(Ojbect... providers)`. You're supposed to be passing providers to register to the constructor, not another ClientConfig object. So basically, your config is not being used in the second case. If it's not working with your first config, then something must be wrong with the configuration.

Comment: I will check if config is working for second case and update.